# Having difficulty getting Site.changePassword() to work

Tags: apex-code, visualforce

I have a custom portal integrated with a custom site, using Apex/Visualforce. I want to provide custom password change functionality on a Visualforce page that's enabled for the site/portal.

The Site static class method is hardly documented and after combing developerforce.com and coming up empty, I figured I would try here. Here's the method (found in the sample ChangePasswordController class)

```
Site.changePassword(newPassword, verifyNewPassword, oldpassword);
```

Here's the kicker. Regardless what data I enter for these values, including respecting all password policies, the method simply returns null and ***does nothing***. It's interesting that in the sample test method provided by Salesforce the assert literally proves this to be the case:

```
/**
 * An apex page controller that exposes the change password functionality
 */
public with sharing class ChangePasswordController {
    public String oldPassword {get; set;}
    public String newPassword {get; set;}
    public String verifyNewPassword {get; set;}        

    public PageReference changePassword() {
        return Site.changePassword(newPassword, verifyNewPassword, oldpassword);
    }     

    public ChangePasswordController() {}

    public static testMethod void testChangePasswordController() {
        // Instantiate a new controller with all parameters in the page
        ChangePasswordController controller = new ChangePasswordController();
        controller.oldPassword = '123456';
        controller.newPassword = 'qwerty1'; 
        controller.verifyNewPassword = 'qwerty1';                

        System.assertEquals(controller.changePassword(),null);                           
    }    
}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance with this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have an `<apex:pageMessages>` element on your VF page? Perhaps the Site class is setting an error message, which you wouldn't see unless you have this element on the page.

Comment: Bingo! Here's what I'm getting: Error:
That operation is only allowed from within an active site.

Comment: problem is, the site is definitely active but it's in a sandbox. So I suppose we have to deploy such code to production without actually testing it?? There's got to be a way to test from a sandbox. Or perhaps this "active" is a different active from the Site Active checkbox? - Thanks again for your help Jeremy!

Comment: That'd be crazy if you can't test it in sandbox. But if you have the Site set to active, I don't know what else it would be.

Comment: Totally crazy. I'm creating a case right now and will let you know what I find out from support.

Comment: The results are in from support. Since I was having users authenticate as a high-volume portal users, regardless of the fact that they are also in my custom Site, the Site.changePassword() method is no longer valid. Therefore, the method to use is System.setPassword(user.Id, newPassword).